# Calculate SOMO35 from netcdf file

Tags: r, netcdf, ozone

I have this netcdf file (with ozone, lat&long variables), from my simulations processes:

```
    3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    float XLAT[west_east,south_north]   (Contiguous storage)  
    standard_name: latitude
    long_name: latitude
   units: degree_north
   _CoordinateAxisType: Lat
    float XLONG[west_east,south_north]   (Contiguous storage)  
        standard_name: longitude
        long_name: longitude
        units: degree_east
        _CoordinateAxisType: Lon
    float o3[west_east,south_north,bottom_top,XTIME]   (Chunking: [160,155,1,1])  
        units: ppmv
        coordinates: XLAT XLONG
        FieldType: 104
        MemoryOrder: XYZ
        description: O3 mixing ratio

 4 dimensions:
    south_north  Size:155
 [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named          south_north BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
    west_east  Size:160
 [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named   west_east BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
    XTIME  Size:8833   *** is unlimited ***
        standard_name: time
        units: minutes since 2018-12-29 00:00:00
        calendar: standard
        axis: T
    bottom_top  Size:1
   [1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension  named bottom_top BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
```

I need to calculate SOMO35 with a R script using Rstudio:

```
      SOMO35 is the Sum of Ozone Means Over 35 ppb is an indicator for health impact         assessment
   recommended by WHO. It is defined as the yearly sum of the daily maximum of 8-
     hour running average over 35 ppb. For each day the maximum of the running  8-hours
     average for O3 is selected and the values over 35 ppb are summed over the whole
     year. If we let Ad
   8 denote the maximum 8-hourly average ozone on day d, during a
     year with Ny days (Ny = 365 or 366), then SOMO35 can be defined as:
    SOMO35 = ∑d=Ny
   d=1 max(Ad
     8 − 35 ppb, 0.0)
  where the max function ensures that only Ad
      8 values exceeding 35 ppb are included.
      The corresponding unit is ppb·days (abbreviated also as ppb·d).
```

I wrote a fragment of the scritpt but doesnt work.

```
 SOMO35_NO_SWC_tmp <- runave(O3_NO_SWC_tmp, n = 8, align = "center")
 SOMO35_NO_SWC_tmp1 <- ifelse(SOMO35_NO_SWC_tmp - 35 < 0, 0, SOMO35_NO_SWC_tmp - 35)
 SOMO35_NO_SWC <- sum(SOMO35_NO_SWC_tmp1)
 rm(SOMO35_NO_SWC_tmp, SOMO35_NO_SWC_tmp1)
```

Anyone could help me please?

Thank you,
Beatrice

Comment: Please make your code reproducible. We have no way of knowing what the format is.